# Bootstrap Date-Picker Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error "Undefined is not a function".

At the end of my body tag, I've got

```
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script href="/static/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the error?  I thought I might be ordering the references wrongly but I reordered them a few different ways with no luck.

Comment: html or a fiddle might help? very likely issue is a typo or something minor `:)` like doc ready invoke call or wrong class name

Comment: Try including `bootstrap.min.js` above `bootstrap-datepicker.js`, and bind the js code in `document.ready`

Comment: @ShaunakD Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Is the path `/static/js/....js` correct? It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/5bhRg/

Comment: @ShaunakD My paths are correct.

Comment: Found my error - I was using href instead of src in the script tag.